# How to upgrade the version of yarn on node:latest docker image?

Tags: node.js, docker, yarnpkg, linuxkit

The official docker image for node is: https://hub.docker.com/_/node. This comes with `yarn` pre-installed at v1.x. I want to upgrade `yarn` to v2. However, I can't tell how `yarn` was installed on this image. It's presumably not via `npm` because if I do `npm list`, `yarn` does not show up in the list. I don't know of another way to install `yarn`. I thought maybe it was via the package manager for `linuxkit`, which I believe is the distribution used by the node docker image. However I looked at the package-manager for linuxkit – as I understand it they just use git clone and there are a list of packages available in `/pkg` in the github repository. However, `yarn` isn't one of those.

Some steps towards an answer, maybe:

1. How is the installed version of yarn on node:latest docker image installed? [Maybe that will inform me as to how I can upgrade it]
2. How can I upgrade `yarn` on a LinuxKit docker image?
3. How can I see the Dockerfile for the base image? [I.e. `node:latest` – is there a Dockerfile for that which tells us how the image was generated? If so that might tell me how `yarn` was installed.]

Comment: All of the `Dockerfile`s are in https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node, did you look there how Yarn is added?

Comment: Looks like the Yarn version is defined by the `YARN_VERSION` var.

Comment: @jonrsharpe It's added via `apk` in those Dockerfiles but `apk` yields `command not found` if I `exec` the container.

Comment: Is it? E.g. https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/cde9414cb2db0be1a911e9070c6c117de7be705a/18/buster/Dockerfile#L50-L68 doesn't use `apk`.

Comment: Not sure. I found this, which suggests it's installed via tarball: https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/issues/351

Answer (score 4):

The [Best Practices Guide](https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/main/docs/BestPractices.md) recommends for (simple) local installs

```
FROM node:6

ENV YARN_VERSION 1.16.0

RUN yarn policies set-version $YARN_VERSION
```

in your Dockerfile. This guide is worth to be read anyway ;-)

Answer (score 4):

If you can do something on runtime,
simply use below command to install the Yarn version you want:

```
yarn set version stable
```

On 2022-11-23, `stable` will install Yarn 3.3.0.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Dockerfile](https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node) it is installed via tarbar in both in [alpine](https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/main/18/alpine3.16/Dockerfile#L86) and [debian](https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/main/18/bullseye/Dockerfile#L59) versions:

```
  && curl -fsSLO --compressed "https://yarnpkg.com/downloads/$YARN_VERSION/yarn-v$YARN_VERSION.tar.gz" \
  && curl -fsSLO --compressed "https://yarnpkg.com/downloads/$YARN_VERSION/yarn-v$YARN_VERSION.tar.gz.asc" \
  && gpg --batch --verify yarn-v$YARN_VERSION.tar.gz.asc yarn-v$YARN_VERSION.tar.gz \
  && mkdir -p /opt \
  && tar -xzf yarn-v$YARN_VERSION.tar.gz -C /opt/ \
  && ln -s /opt/yarn-v$YARN_VERSION/bin/yarn /usr/local/bin/yarn \
  && ln -s /opt/yarn-v$YARN_VERSION/bin/yarnpkg /usr/local/bin/yarnpkg \
  && rm yarn-v$YARN_VERSION.tar.gz.asc yarn-v$YARN_VERSION.tar.gz \
```

You can use the similar commands to download and use `ln` to create symlink for your version like above.